# How do I specify a command line to open a document for Java System.exec() for Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos

I am helping a colleague set up some GUI programming tools I have written in Java.

I need to "open", "start" or "launch" a document using Java System.exec().  For example, I want to open some text file in the default editor, possibly positioned at line 20, column 50.  Or I want to start the default browser and display a particular HTML page.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "open" command, which opens a file (or URL or directory) just as if you had double-clicked on it, e.g.:

```
$ open http://slashdot.org # Opens in your web browser
$ open $HOME/foo.txt # Opens in your text editor
$ open $HOME # Opens in the Finder
```

I have verified that you can use that command with [`Runtime.exec()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: Thanks - looks like what I need; we'll try it shortly and get back to you.

Comment: BTW: Specifically we used `open -e ...` because that opens things like scripts in an editor instead with their default app, the shell.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Desktop.open()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) which handles exactly that in an OS-independent manner.
 
So you do not need to mess around with Runtime.exec()

Comment: Good idea; I was forced to target Java 1.1 for so long I keep forgetting about things added in Java 5 and 6.  But for now, until I can mod the application, I need a System.exec() command line.

Comment: @Software: I'm sorry that you feel that way. Be assure that this was not my intention. I'm genuinely sorry and sympathetic for everyone forced to work with ancient software like that. The rest was meant as a light-hearted jab (mostly at companies that still use Java 1.1-era software, but I admit that was not really visible).

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: how would System.exec() help if you cannot modify the application? At the very line whery you'd put the System.exec() you can also put Desktop.open(). Btw: ProcessBuilder should be used instead of System.exec() as it handles parameters in a more robust way.

Comment: @a_horse: probably configurable launch commands. It's pretty common.

Comment: Yes, the application already has configurable launch commands.